# How to place component on screen React

Tags: reactjs

I am a total beginner in react. I’m following this tutorial to create a project.
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/create-gameoflife-with-react-in-one-hour-8e686a410174
I am stuck in the line "Update App.js to import our Game.js and place the Game component on the screen. Now we can see a completely black game board." , dont understand what to do, can anyone please help.
I have added the line import './Game.js'; but nothing changes from the output

Comment: It's not enough to import Game.js. You should add the component in the hierarchy returned from `render()` function. Something like `return <Game />;` or `return (<div><Game /></div>);`. And I think the import should be something like `import Game from './Game';`.

Comment: @mihai1990 thanks adding it like import Game from './Game'; was what was required. Thank you